# Is there a standard definition of fractal dimension?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

There are many definitions/methods of calculating the fractal dimension (Hausdorff, Box-counting, Higuchi, Katz, Correlation, etc. dimensions) and I think the main one is the Hausdorff dimension $D$ defined as:

$$D=-\frac{\log{N}}{\log{\epsilon}}$$

where $N$ is the number of measured units and $\epsilon$ is the scaling factor [[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension)]. Are all these different definitions the estimates of the same fractal dimension (Hausdorff) or are they independent measures of complexity?

Wikipedia suggests the latter but in this [paper](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Elittlab/Site/Publications_files/Esteller_2001.pdf) for example the estimation of methods are compared with a theoretical fractal dimension (Hausdorff) of a synthetic time series.

Comment: Many, but not all, of these are independent measures. However, "complexity" is not necessarily what they measure. For many applications in mathematics they are used as "measuring sticks" to measure the size of sets in various ways.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the answer. I couldn't find a better word (that is not fractal dimension) than complexity. So all of the measures used in the paper must be equivalent (specifically I'm more interested in Katz fractal dimension). And I didn't quite understand what you mean by the 'size of sets'.

Comment: The dimension you $D$ you've written is actually the box dimension. The Hausdorff dimension is defined by slightly more measure theoretic means (futher down the examples list on the wiki page you linked). Generally speaking the different notions of fractal dimensions don't agree with one another, but do agree for "nice" fractals.

Comment: @Zorngo Actually I've seen in a youtube course where the instructor called the formula Hausdorff dimension. I also noticed that wikipedia defines something else for that. I guess what you mean by "nice fractals" are Weierstrass cosine function (in the paper), Koch's curve, and other mathematical (theoretical) fractals (?). Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: The Koch curve is certainly nice, it's given as the attractor of an iterated function system satisfying the so called open-set condition has therefore has nice dimensionality properties. The Weierstrass function is slightly tricker, but there's a nice discussion of it in Chapter 11 of "Fractal Geometry" by Falconer.

Comment: The notion of dimension given in your post appears to be the similarity dimension of the attractor of an iterated function system, but could also be the Minkowski-Bouligand (or box-counting) dimension, after you take a limit.  It is not quite clear what you mean by that expression.  It is definitely not the Hausdorff dimension  If a space is "sufficiently regular" (whatever that means), various notions of dimension do align, but they are all quite different.